# sql join on Nearest greater than Value

Tags: sql-server

If i have the following database structure:

tbl1

```
|id        | EYearMonth       | 
| 1        |     1617         |  
| 2        |     1618         |  
| 3        |     1619         |  
| 4        |     1620         |     
| 5        |     1621         |  
| 6        |     1622         | 
| 7        |     1623         | 
| 8        |     1624         | 
| 9        |     1625         | 
| 10       |     1626         | 
| 11       |     1627         | 
| 12       |     1628         |
```

Tbl2

```
|id        | Value            | Serial#
| 1        |     1617         | 1068 
| 2        |     1618         | 1104
| 3        |     1624         | 1215
```

What I really want, is the following:

Result

```
|id        | EYearMonth       | Serial#
| 1        |     1617         | 1068
| 2        |     1618         | 1104
| 3        |     1619         | 1104
| 4        |     1620         | 1104  
| 5        |     1621         | 1104  
| 6        |     1622         | 1104  
| 7        |     1623         | 1104  
| 8        |     1624         | 1215
| 9        |     1625         | 1215
| 10       |     1626         | 1215
| 11       |     1627         | 1215
| 12       |     1628         | 1215
```

How can I make this Result? Please Help Me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` and `TOP` for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1 t1
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 t2.[Serial#]
    FROM tbl2 t2
    WHERE t2.Value <= t1.EYearMonth
    ORDER BY t2.Value DESC
)t2
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/486157)</kbd>

Comment: I think that should be `ORDER BY t2.value DESC` , since there is no guarantee that the serials will follow this pathern:)

Comment: @sagi, yup! Thanks again for saving my a**. Must be time to rest.

Comment: I tried this code but the value of Serial# Column in result tbl be equal with 1215

Answer (score 0):

The following query will work:

```
SELECT
    T1.id,
    T1.EYearMonth,
    T2.Serial#
FROM tbl1 T1
INNER JOIN Tbl2 T2
    ON tbl1.EYearMonth = Tbl2.Value
```